# Azure function app using CSOM and Azure AD for authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, csom

I'm not sure if this is possible but my objective is an Azure function app that can use the SharePoint CSOM. I'm stuck on how to do the authorization with no user credentials. I've pieced together the code below but it throws a 401 unauthorized. This could be a configuration issue which I've had problems with when doing a JavaScript application and a Web Api. But I'm also wondering if this is even feasible or if I'm going about it the wrong way. Some key points before the code:

1. My front end demo app was created with a secret to be used in authentication
2. My Api demo app was granted API permissions to Azure AD, Microsoft Graph, and SharePoint
3. My Api demo app exposed an API and the front end demo app was added as an authorized client app

```
private static async Task ProcessMessageAsync(string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    const string mName = "ProcessMessageAsync()";
    string resource = "https://my-Portal.onmicrosoft.com/demoapp-api"; //demoapp-api with permission to sharepoint
    string clientId = "guid-of-demoapp-frontend"; //demoapp-frontend
    string clientSecret = "secret-from-demoapp-frontend"; //demoapp-frontend secret
    string siteUrl = "https://my-portal.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site"; //sharepoint site
    string authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-portal.onmicrosoft.com";
    try
    {
        using (ClientContext ctx = await GetClientContext(authorityUri, siteUrl, resource, clientId, clientSecret))
        {
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            log.LogInformation($"found site : {web.Title}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("***Unexpected Exception in {0} *** : {1}", mName, ex.Message);
        log.LogInformation("***Unexpected Exception in {0} *** : {1}", mName, ex.Message);
        while (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            ex = ex.InnerException;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
public async static Task<ClientContext> GetClientContext(string authorityuri, string siteUrl, string resource, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityuri);
    AuthenticationResult ar = await GetAccessToken(authorityuri, resource, clientId, clientSecret);
    string token = ar.AccessToken;
    var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
    {
        e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + ar.AccessToken;
    };
    return ctx;
}
static async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
        resource,  // the resource (app) we are going to access with the token
        clientCredential);  // the client credentials
    return authenticationResult;
}
```

**Update**
After further research I think the problem might be that I was using delegate permissions and instead I need application permissions (which require that I have admin access in the directory).

Answer (score 0):

You get token with following code:

```
    AuthenticationResult ar = await GetAccessToken(authorityuri, resource, clientId, clientSecret);
    string token = ar.AccessToken;
```

However, the token you get can only be used to access the resource you specified as the parameter. In your case, it is `"https://my-Portal.onmicrosoft.com/demoapp-api"`.

So, you can only use that token to access your endpoint web API, not sharepoint directly.

Comment: I do have a few articles that claim this is possible. For example [link]https://bob1german.com/2017/06/24/az-func-csom/ and [link]https://mmsharepoint.wordpress.com/tag/csom/

Comment: Checked the two articles. The fact is that they only have one azure function app, there is no other endpoint. And  their resources are specified as their sharepoint site. So, surly, they will get right tokens for accessing their sharepoint sites.  But your case is different from them.

Comment: I've been experimenting with the code to more closely match those links and I think the issue is that you need to grant the function app non-delegate permissions and that requires you be an admin for the directory (and I am not an admin).